# Rails routes.rb proper syntax for resources :users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wanting to do these two routings... but I can't figure out the proper syntax... I am pretty new at rails.

```
resources :users do
  get :increase_workouts, on: :collection
  end
  resources :users do
  get :increase_workoutseconds, on: :collection
  end
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Basically, I am trying to use ajax to call on a ruby controller action to update my model like this.

```
function alertFunc() {
    if(jwplayer().getState() == "playing" && timeWatched < duration){
        timeWatched++
        $.ajax("/users/increase_workoutseconds")
    } else if (timeWatched >= duration){
        clearInterval(theInterval);
    }    
    else {
        clearInterval(theInterval)
    }    
}
```

The action is in the users controller under the increase_workouts action.
I am also trying to call the increase_workoutseconds action. Hence, the two different attempts to do the resources :users do.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: could you show what routes do you expect to be generated?

Comment: I am trying to call on a controller action using ajax to update my user model for the person that is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I am still learning how routes work in rails, but looks like this was an easier way to do it.

```
get '/users/increase_workoutseconds', to: 'users#increase_workoutseconds'
get '/users/increase_workouts', to: 'users#increase_workouts'
```